# Image not getting displayed in imageView

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, imageview

Why my image not getting displayed in imageView?

```
    var image : Bitmap?=null

    longToast(obj?.image?.url.toString())

    try {
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(obj?.image?.url.toString())
        imagePhoto.setImageBitmap(image)
        longToast("abc")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message
    }
```

The image is not null as I saw the `toast` displayed

```
https://...../tempory.jpg
```

Comment: you call `decodeFile` - a "file" here is something in your local filesystem - not a resource pointed by `http://xxx` uri - you can use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) in such cases

Comment: try using `Glide` https://medium.com/@vlonjatgashi/using-glide-with-kotlin-5e345b557547

Comment: That is an url, so you need to download it first before showing it. Consider using image loader library like `Glide` to handle these tasks for you

Comment: `decodeFile` can't handle internet locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile` can not handle url

To load image from url you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), this library is recommended by Google. From doc:

> Note: There are several libraries that follow best practices for
>   loading images. You can use these libraries in your app to load images
>   in the most optimized manner. We recommend the Glide library

Add Glide to your project:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

Then

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(obj?.image?.url.toString())
.into(imagePhoto)
```